# How to add unique ID to an XML formated MSSQL SELECT query with DISTINCT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to create a simple MSSQL `SELECT` query and format it in order to create an XML document.

I can format the XML simple in the following way:

```
SELECT  

'<UNB_TIERART uuid="MY_UNIQUE_ID" > <TIERKLASSE>' 

GRUPPE

+'</TIERKLASSE> </UNB_TIERART>'

FROM [MAPAGENT].[dbo].[ARTEN]
```

Is there a method to replace `MY_UNIQUE_ID` with a variable e.g a number which increases by one for each entry?

Comment: Have you considered using FOR XML clause with ROW_NUMBER() OVER?

Comment: That should be a DISTINCT(GRUPPE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create xml document, why not entirely in SQL Server using following FOR XML syntax?

Take a look at this solution:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Gruppe) AS '@uuid',
GRUPPE AS 'TIERKLASSE'
FROM (VALUES('G1'), ('G2')) T(Gruppe) [MAPAGENT].[dbo].[ARTEN]
FOR XML PATH('UNB_TIERART')
```

If you also need a root (full XML), just append ROOT('root name') like below:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Gruppe) AS '@uuid',
GRUPPE AS 'TIERKLASSE'
FROM (VALUES('G1'), ('G2')) T(Gruppe) --YOUR TABLE
FOR XML PATH('UNB_TIERART'), ROOT('ROOT')
```

The latter produces:

```
<ROOT>
  <UNB_TIERART uuid="1">
    <TIERKLASSE>G1</TIERKLASSE>
  </UNB_TIERART>
  <UNB_TIERART uuid="2">
    <TIERKLASSE>G2</TIERKLASSE>
  </UNB_TIERART>
</ROOT>
```

If you need distinct gruppe, apply distinct to your base table:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Gruppe) AS '@uuid',
GRUPPE AS 'TIERKLASSE'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Gruppe FROM [YOUR TABLE]
) DistincResult
FOR XML PATH('UNB_TIERART'), ROOT('ROOT')
```

Comment: SORRY!  I forgot to add the  DISTINCT(GRUPPE) clause...it almost worked

Comment: GREAT!  That worked a treat. I was trying to use DISTINCT(GRUPPE) which throws an error!! Is it normal that the <ROOT> tag isn´t closed?

Comment: It should be closed. Do you have unclosed ROOT?

Comment: Ah...just realised that when I use right click>copy in the results windows the end is cut off. Maybe there is another way to copy results which go over more than one line, but I had to download the result in csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FOR XML PATH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx).

Something like below:

```
;WITH TestData(GRUPPE) AS
(
    SELECT 'row1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'row2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'row3'
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY GRUPPE ASC) as '@uuid' ,GRUPPE as TIERKLASSE
FROM TestData
FOR XML PATH('UNB_TIERART')
```